# Transfer variable values to another page

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a SELECT in a page, that lists the fields from a database. One of these fields, will be a link (company's name), which will redirect to a page containing the informations about this field. How do I transfer this data? Every listed company will have a page. I just need to understand how does it work, because I tried using POST methods and I've got a thousand errors.

I appreciate any help!

Loop and fields

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY nomevaga") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<div class="field1">'.$array['field1'].'</div>
<div class="company"><a href="company.php">'.$array['company'].'</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: i would like to suggest not to use get method because it is not secure.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @alok GET is just as "safe" as POST/cookies/headers or anything the user sends to the server.

Comment: @h2ooooooo your value can be seen in url if you use get and i can change that value to anything

Comment: @alok And you can change POST values, cookies, headers, user agents and everything else as well. Never trust ANYTHING coming from the user in any way.

Comment: So, what should I use then? And how? Is it ok to use GET just like Russell Kenward shows below?

Comment: @Anna Use whichever you want. GET doesn't require a <form> to be sent to use (therefore good for inline stuff and buttons) but POST allows you to "hide" (technically no, but to the average user they shouldn't be sneaking around development consoles ;)) the data from the URL, making the URL cleaner. Both are as secure as the other - you should protect yourself from SQL injections in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY nomevaga") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<div class="field1">'.$array['field1'].'</div>
<div class="company"><a href="company.php?name='.$array['company'].'">'.$array['company'].'</a></div>';
}
?>

company.php
<?php
  $companyName='defaultName';
  if(isset($_GET['name']&&!empty($_GET['name']))
  {
     $companyName=$_GET['name'];
  }
  //handle with  $companyName
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nomevaga' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in ***companies-list.php on line 49

Line: <div class="company"><a href="company.php?name=$array['company']">'.$array['company'].'</a></div>

Comment: <a href="company.php?name='.$array['company'].'">' the code is updated

Comment: Done! Now, I need to show the company's information from the database. Can I just use a simple SELECT from MySQL database? Is it gonna understand that it needs to print the information relevant to the company passed via GET?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value via URL and use GET:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY nomevaga") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $company = $array['company'];
    echo "<div class='field1'>".$array['field1']."</div><div class='company'><a href='company.php?comp=$company'>".$company."</a></div>";
}
?>
```

Then in company.php use:

```
$company = $_GET['comp'];
```

EDIT: Using GET and URL parameters can give major security issues as any user can simply replace the value in the URL with thier own, and depending if you are using the variable to load php files or jamming it into an SQL statement this can lead to XSS and SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Russell!